# C# DPAPI DataProtector equivalent in python 3

Tags: python, c#, dpapi

I have code written in C# that creates DataProtector which then is used to protect tokens in config

C# code

```
   //constructor code
   var appLocalDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(localApplicationData, "<example_dir>"));
   var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(appLocalDir, builder => { builder.ProtectKeysWithDpapi(); });
   _dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("<example_purpose>");
    
    //protector usage
    public string Token
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _dataProtector.Unprotect(_token);
            }
            catch
            {
                _token = null;
                return null;
            }
        }
        set => _token = _dataProtector.Protect(value);
    }
```

I need to create similar protector in python in order to save token retrieved by python code to be used by c# code.

Is there any python lib for such things? I need my python code to have exactly the same output as C#'s one in order to read the token using provided example

So far I couldn't find any solution that would work on windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking many different solutions I found one that works for me.
I used python.NET package to load required C# .dll files and used them in python code.